# Mediawiki невозможно редактировать common.css

Tags: php, mediawiki

Пытаюсь редактировать файл common.css, но не позволяет, выдвигая следующую ошибку:

> У вас нет прав на выполнение действия «редактирование этой страницы»
>   по следующим причинам:
>
> Эта страница содержит интерфейсное сообщение программного обеспечения.
>   Во избежание вандализма её изменение запрещено. Чтобы добавить или
>   изменить перевод этого сообщения во всех вики, пожалуйста, используйте
>   сайт локализации MediaWiki translatewiki.net У вас нет прав на
>   редактирование этой CSS-страницы, поскольку её изменение может
>   повлиять на всех посетителей.

Движок стоит на Ubuntu 16 на VPS-сервере, в чем может быть причина?

[image: Изображение ошибки]

Answer (score 0):

Решил. 
В LocalSettings.php прописал следующие права для групп пользователей.
Для версии 1.32:

```
$wgGroupPermissions['user']['editinterface'] = true;
$wgGroupPermissions['user']['editsitecss'] = true;
```

Для версии ниже этой нужна только первая строчка:

```
$wgGroupPermissions['user']['editinterface'] = true;
```